# Reading Multiples excel tables having variable rows lenght in the same Worksheet using c#

Tags: c#, .net, excel, datatables, worksheet

So i have an excel file containing a worksheet with 4 tables
[My excel worsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKO18.png)

i want to be able to get all of those tables to separate dataTable knowing that the lenght of the rows can change (rows can be added or deleted)

I've tried using oleDb which work just fine with the first table in the worksheet but when i try to get the second one (by specifying the starting row) it give me the second table with all the others tables in one datatable :/ 
here is my code :

```
 public static System.Data.DataTable getTableSelection(string file, string sheet, string starting = "", string finish = "")
    {
        string ConStr;
        string HDR;
        HDR = "YES";
        ConStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="
            + file + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=" + HDR + ";IMEX=0\"";
        OleDbConnection cnn = new OleDbConnection(ConStr);
        string query = "select * from ["
                            + sheet + "$" + (starting != "" ? starting + ":" + finish : "") + "]";
        Console.WriteLine(query);
        OleDbCommand oconn = new OleDbCommand(query, cnn);
        OleDbDataAdapter adp = new OleDbDataAdapter(oconn);
        System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
        adp.Fill(dt);
        cnn.Close();
        return dt;
    }
```

Sorry for my bad english , hope you understand !! 
love StackOverflow

Comment: Why do you have a colon after the variable "finish"?

Comment: @jdweng for example if i call the method with this parameter Tools.getTableSelection("G:\\Classeur.xlsx", "Produits","A14","D");   i get this query :  select * from [Produits$A14:D]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i found a solution which consist on joining all my tables to get a all the fields i need and then transform it to a datatable by using oleDb query ; my query look like this : `select * from (([Sheet1$A:D9] INNER JOIN [Sheet1$A14:D21] ON [Sheet1$A:D9].primaryKey=[Sheet1$A14:D21].primaryKey) INNER JOIN [Sheet2$A26:M33] ON [Sheet2$A26:M33].primaryKey=[Sheet1$A14:D21].primaryKey)`

but still , i am not being able to get the table without specifying where it should end :/